# discord.py the welcome command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

why does it's not working for me?

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
   await client.get_channel(965214301520560178).send(f"{member.name} has joined")
```

thanks for the helpers!

I tried to make a welcome command in discord.py

Comment: Hi @omer raz, welcome to stack overflow. Please explain what's happening in more detail. For example, give us the error it is giving, or what isn't happening.

Comment: there is no error, it's just not working.

Comment: when i try to add new user it's just not doin nothing

Comment: @omerraz, do you have the necessary intents enabled on your Discord Developer Portal? Always check the documentation. See [`async def on_member_join(member)`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.on_member_join). You need the [`Intents.members` intent](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Intents.members). And accordingly, you need to change how you create the Bot/Client. Use [`intents = discord.Intents.all()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Intents.all), the easiest way. Then `client = Client(intents=intents)`.

Comment: To add to the above, you need to enable the relevant Intents in the discord developer portal too. Enabling all intents as the above suggest; you will need to enable all the corresponding privleged intents in the discord developer portal as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ping the new member and that is the part that doesn't work (a bit unclear) it should be:

```
await client.get_channel(965214301520560178).send(f"<@{member.id}> has joined")
```

also, make sure to check if the bot has the necessary permissions and/or intents